# Explicitly use Highlight.js auto detected language for a code block

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Highlight.js does a reasonable job of automatically highlighting blocks of code in an unknown language. Sometimes as I'm writing a post which has blocks from multiple languages, console commands, log files, etc. I'm quite pleased with the automatic results, so I don't put a language tag on my code fences like this:

````
```python
[...]

```
````

I just leave it blank. However when I tag *my question* with a language tag like [python], I know Stack Exchange has a default syntax highlighting language for that tag, which that gets applied to all un-tagged blocks (i.e., all un-tagged blocks get highlighted as Python if you tag the question with that)

I'm wondering is there a way to explicitly override that default with the auto detection behaviour instead (on a code block)? Or otherwise, detect the language highlight.js chooses for the block (I think there is a TIO link on the highlight.js website that lets you obtain this info, but I'd rather not go off-site).

---

To be clear, the use case for this is when I don't know what language is appropriate for a block of code (is it Bash, PowerShell or [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)? Which language looks good for a log file?), I want some algorithm to decide for me a reasonable suggestion and then I can choose to keep that as good enough, or search in detail the set of supported languages to see if I can find one better. I hope that's clear.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Per the FAQ post [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), you can use the identifier `default` or any other invalid identifier to make it auto-detect.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog is default a SE /highlight.js keyword, or an example of an invalid identifier? I'm asking in the rare case "default" later becomes a valid identifier with it's own syntax highlighting. If it's a keyword for lang-autodetect or whatever then that's perfect thanks!

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog all I can find in that question, is that language tags can be associated with `null`, `default`, or `lang-foo` to specify the behaviour for questions with that language tag. Do those hints  `null` and `default` also work for code blocks? I can't find any mention of it

Comment: @Greedo it does work for code blocks (see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfhYF.png) of me testing it - it detected C# for a `default` code block in a python-tagged post). The current revision of that answer has gone through some extensive edits since the last time [an SE staff edited it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/184109/101); the staff revision was more general and explicitly listed `default`.

Comment: Re *"...blocks from multiple languages, console commands, log files etc. I'm quite pleased with the automatic results"*: I have never seen this work properly. It is a complete mess in most cases. Can you add some examples of where it works?

Comment: Re *"Highlight.js does a reasonable job of automatically highlighting blocks of code in an unknown language"*: No, Highlight.js creates a lot of busy work that should not be necessary, cleaning up its weird syntax highlighting.

Comment: In its current state, it would be better to turn syntax highlighting off completely, unless there are *explicit* syntax highlighting hints. It is severely broken.